# How to make Sublime text build execute on numpad enter?

Tags: go, sublimetext, sublime-build, gosublime

I use GoSublime inside sublime text for Golang development.
Pressing `Ctrl + B` gives me the build pane, then I need to type a command e.g., `go run main.go` and press `Enter`. When I want to execute a command using `numpad Enter` it doesn't work. How to make it work with `numpad Enter` too?

I checked the default keymap in sublime text it provides only the following key bindings for build tool

```
    { "keys": ["f7"], "command": "build" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "build" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "build", "args": {"select": true} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+break"], "command": "exec", "args": {"kill": true} },
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

The only suggestion I can give is to try using <kbd>numpad_enter</kbd> both with <kbd>NumLock</kbd> on and off, and see if it makes a difference. I'm running OS X and using the standard wired Apple keyboard with a numpad, and I'm also running Linux in a virtual machine. When I open up the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) and run the command

```py
sublime.log_input(True)
```

then refocus the file I'm working on, pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> (the <kbd>Enter</kbd> equivalent on the main keyboard) yields

```
key evt: enter
```

in the console, whereas hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keypad yields

```
key evt: keypad_enter
```

This behavior does not change in OS X or Linux (I haven't tried in my Windows VM yet) regardless of how <kbd>NumLock</kbd> is set. If you're on Windows or Linux with a Windows keyboard, it *may* change, but I doubt it.

---

The reason Sublime does this is because <kbd>numpad_enter</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> send different keycodes to the program. Sublime is looking for a certain keycode (the one sent by <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to submit the contents of popup menus and whatnot, and ignores the code sent by <kbd>numpad_enter</kbd>. Unfortunately, because this is built-in behavior, there is no setting or key binding that can be set to override it.

The only other possibility I can think of is to use a utility for your OS to reprogram you <kbd>numpad_enter</kbd> to send the same keycode as <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I'm not terribly familiar with it, but for Windows I've heard that [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) is a pretty useful utility, and as far as I can tell is free. You can [remap](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) keys with it rather easily. You'll have to google for other utilities if you're on OS X or Linux.

Good luck!